# How to replace color by photoshop in this case

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]
How do I replace red color of this image to blue(1800ff) ? (I get issue with gradient around)

Comment: How well does this example image represent the real life scenario? Because if the actual task is to change the color of a circle with a single color fill, the best thing to do would be to redraw the circle in a new layer with any color I want. Not just because of simplicity, but to retain the quality of the image. Especially if the background is more complex than a single color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the actual shape is much more complex. This answer covers them if the coloring is still one color on white background, only the edges are more or less fading to white like in the example.

One trick is to mask a solid 1800ff layer with a layer mask and have a new white background layer. If your white-red image layer is pasted to the layer mask as is you will get this:

[image]

You must stretch the contrast of the mask to cover range from black to white + invert the scale. Applying curves to the mask makes it as single operation:

[image]

To paste something to the layer mask Alt+Click the mask icon in the layers panel. Then Paste in Place (=Ctrl+Shift+V). Curves can be applied to the mask if the mask icon is selected.

Flatten the image if needed.

Comment: Please explain me more in these step
"You must stretch the contrast of the mask to cover range from black to white + invert the scale. Applying curves to the mask makes it as single operation"

Comment: @M-ChauNguyen I clicked the layer mask icon  in the layers panel (after inserting a layer mask and copying the original image to the mask) . Then I went to menu item  Image > Adjustments > Curves. The drawn falling curve mapped light grey parts to white and white parts to black. to make the background area fully transparent (=black in the mask), the main shape area fully opaque and to keep the gradual transition from opaque to transparent.